# How to automatically resend devise confirmation emails after e.g. two days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to "stimulate" users not having confirmed their login by resending them their devise confirmation email after e.g. two days. I was wondering whether this is available by default - of whether someone has already implemented something similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by implementing cron-job in your application. Please have a look into whenever gem "https://github.com/javan/whenever".

Here is the following process.
You need to write a method or a rake task, which checks the users table where users.confirmed_at = NULL and duration between current date and confirmation_sent_at is greater than 2 days. Now you have all the users who did not confirm their account after registration. Now go through each record and send the confirmation mail again.

Note: you need to run this rake task once in a day.

Hope it will work :)